Why did Miles Morales read "Alchemax" as "Roxxon" in this scene?
In Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Miles Morales discovered that the spider that bit him was branded with "Alchemax 1250M117":


Miles: Roxxon

Alchemax and Roxxon are two separate corporations in the Marvel Universe, each with its own unique origins, leaders, and operations.
Why did Miles Morales read "Alchemax" as "Roxxon" in this scene?

Note that this is a deleted scene. It doesn't necessarily make sense because the audio and visuals are still being finalised.

@Valorum Deleted scene? Its from Alternate Universe Cut. I mentioned it clearly in the question.

The 'Alternate Universe Mode' available on the Bluray features a wide selection of storyboard elements and deleted scenes, jumbled into something that resembles a coherent film; https://www.polygon.com/2019/3/19/18271035/spider-verse-alternate-universe-mode-comparison-easter-eggs. "unseen, unfinished and unused footage, which shows alternate scenarios for certain scenes" - It is not, however, a complete film, nor does it have internal consistency or continuity.

So alternate scene/director's cut/universal cut/extended cut scenes are not allowed here?

They're absolutely allowed, but you need to recognise that there might not be a satisfying answer.

As the Alternate Universe Mode was pieced together from unfinished and unused footage, there may be various inconsistencies. This was likely the result of a line-reading and storyboards being spliced together from different versions of the script.
